# Tappable portions within a string for SwiftUI

Tags: text, swiftui

I'm trying to add tappable segments to a Text and I have most of it but I cannot make an array of Texts with .onTapGestures.  How can I add the tap gestures to the Texts.
The goal is to have a string such as "here is a phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx and here is a link: xxx.com.  Go for it." and have xxx-xx-xxx and xxx.com tappable.

````
@available(iOS 14, *)
struct ConversationText: View {
    
    var text: String
    var connectMessageType: ConnectMessageType
    var stringArray = [String]()
    var phones = [String]()
    var weblinks = [String]()
    var textArray = [Text]()
    
    init(text: String, connectMessageType: ConnectMessageType) {
        self.text = text
        self.connectMessageType = connectMessageType
        
        stringArray = text.components(separatedBy: " ")
        phones = phones(from: text) ?? [String]()
        weblinks = weblinks(from: text) ?? [String]()
        textArray = makeTexts(from: stringArray)
    }
    
    var myColor: Color {
        connectMessageType == .me ? .secondaryYellow : .primaryBlue
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        textArray.reduce(Text(""), { $0 + $1 })
    }
    
    func phones(from text: String) -> [String]? {
        Tappables().getPhoneNumbers(from: self.text)
    }
    
    func weblinks(from text: String) -> [String]? {
        Tappables().getWebLinks(from: self.text)
    }
    
    func makeTexts(from stringArray: [String]) -> [Text] {
        var textArray = [Text]()
        for string in stringArray {
                if phones.contains(string) {
                    let text = Text(string+" ")
                        .foregroundColor(myColor)
//                        .onTapGesture {
//                            startCall(number: string, user: nil)
//                        }
                    textArray.append(text)
                } else if weblinks.contains(string) {
                    let text = Text(string+" ")
                        .foregroundColor(myColor)
//                        .onTapGesture {
//                            if let url = URL(string: string),
//                               UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
//                                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
//                        }
                    textArray.append(text)
                } else {
                    textArray.append(Text(string+" "))
                }
        }
        
        return textArray
    }
}```
````

Comment: [Here is an article](https://betterprogramming.pub/swiftui-pain-links-in-text-b31319783c9e) that may help.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, that doesn't take me there because it's text is hard-coded and it  doesn't address taps for phone calls.

Comment: Format presented string with Markdown (you can use custom URL schema to handle open inside app).

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible approach - use string formatted by Markdown.

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

[image: demo]

A main part:

```
Text("here is a phone: [xxx-xxx-xxxx](tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx) and here is a link: [xxx.com](asperi://apple.com). Go for it.")
    .onOpenURL {
        print(">> got: \($0)")
    }
```

[Complete findings & code](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/Add_URL_in_Text.md)

Comment: Thank you.  I should have mentioned that I have to support iOS 14.

Comment: can we inject any string within () ? If I inject, the text is not considering it as link anymore, and treat it as text.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct TCAndPPView: View {
    
    let mainString: AttributedString
    
    init() {
        var string = AttributedString("By continuing you acknowlegde that you have read and agree to our")
        
        // Terms of Conditions
        var tappableTCText = AttributedString(" Terms of Conditions")
        tappableTCText.link = URL(string: "TC://")
        tappableTCText.foregroundColor = Color.white
        tappableTCText.font = Font.mpCaptionSemi
        tappableTCText.underlineStyle = .single
        string.append(tappableTCText)
        
        // Privacy Policy
        var tappablePPText = AttributedString(" Privacy Policy")
        tappablePPText.link = URL(string: "PP://")
        tappablePPText.foregroundColor = Color.white
        tappablePPText.font = Font.mpCaptionSemi
        tappablePPText.underlineStyle = .single
        
        var tappableAndText = AttributedString(" and")
        string.append(tappableAndText)
        
        string.append(tappablePPText)
        
        self.mainString = string
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(mainString)
            .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
                if url.absoluteString == "PP://"{
                    print("Privacy Policy link clicked")
                }else if url.absoluteString == "TC://"{
                    print("Terms of Conditions link clicked")
                }
                return .discarded
            })
            .font(.mpCaptionSemi)
            .padding(.all, 15)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .lineSpacing(6)
            .tint(Color.white)
    }
}
```